# How to implement an RSS feed of a site within alfresco share?

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I am still learning alfresco and trying to get the feed dashlets to display a custom feed in share. The end goal is to have some sort of workflow in which the editing of certain components on a site site page within alfresco generate a feed element which will then be picked up by the feed dashlet. For now to test I created an xml feed file and put it in a document space in a collaborative site that was set to public and put its link in the feeds dashlet config but that doesn't work. Is there anyway to implement the functionality I'm after?

Comment: How are you getting the URL of the feed to give to the dashlet? And if you try accessing the same URL in a standalone feed reader, does that work correctly? Finally, any errors in either the browser JS error log, or in the server logs?

Comment: using the url from the meta-data details of the XML document. The repo is on a remote server but the share is local, so I do substitute the localhost portion of the url for the repo's address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 options:

1. Create your own Dashlet. The current RSS-Feed Dashlet connects to the http connector(share-config-custom.xml), this is an external connector for which authentication is required. So copy the RSS-Feed Dashlet and rip this part out.
2. According to this [JIRA enhancement](https://issues.alfresco.com/jira/browse/MNT-2322) , in Alfresco Enterprise 4.1.4 you can read internal Share Feeds! So this means you probably won't have to do any customization. So grap the SVN/GIT source of Enterprise tree and use Alfresco's code to build the Dashlet or extend/override it.

Comment: I tried another addon (multi rss) already which also didn't work. I figured the issue(s) could be due to some internal mechanism.

Comment: Hmm, strange. I've developed such a Dashlet before and it worked. Almost all the RSS-Feeds within Share are generated through the repository. So you need to point you Dashlet directly to the source and it will work

Comment: I've just looked through the rss-feed dashlet and I don't see any reference to that authenticated feed connector. In fact based on my search the only things that use that connector are the activity-list, blog, discussion and documentlibrary feed component. The rss-feed dashlet just uses a plain ol' http connector acording to the js  controllers

Comment: I'm sorry my bad, it's the http connector so you need to remove that one. probably you'll only need to change feed.util.js file which does the get. And in the config of you dashlet only fill in the part after alfresco/service or share/proxy/alfresco-feed

Comment: btw when you say in the config, do you mean the XML config file or another? Also I should mention that my repository sits on a remote as opposed to local so I may/do need a connector

Comment: Additionally I do not think that the http connector is used. Reason being I put a debugging output in that area of code which never gets called but the getValidRSSUri() method in that file gets called. Odd.

Comment: You shouldn't rip it apart! you should override the share webscript to use another file. And put your copy over there.

Comment: can't override it. The connector used is in another file (Asyn-rssfeeds)and that one's used by other share feeds  also (doclibrary and activity lists) not sure how it is called yet hence I won't be able to find a way overwrite/ride until I know.

Comment: Don't override the util itself. copy it and make another. then override the rss-feed dashlet to use your newly created one.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28746/discussion-between-tahir-malik-and-dark-star1)